# Error in Lua Repl.it - User Input not functioning correctly

Tags: lua

In this program: https://repl.it/EvM6, io.read() should cause input to be assigned to a variable, which is then printed to the screen. But, an odd error appears, which reads,

> "{"command":"input","data":"foo\n","error":""}".

Why does this error occur? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The function `io.read()` was substituted with custom one. The result returned by standard `io.read()` will be different.

A quick-and-dirty way to fix it:

```
local io_read_orig = io.read
function io.read()
  return (
    loadstring(
      "return "..io_read_orig():match[[^{"command":".-","data":(".*"),"error":".*"}$]]
    )():gsub("\n$","")
  )
end

-- By StarBuck
print("Type something, then press enter.")
local input = io.read()
print(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an engineer at Repl.it. This was a bug in our Lua REPL implementation. It's now fixed. I apologize for the confusion.